# Find closest location improvement

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geolocation, distance

I found the following algorithm to find the closest point given a location:

```
function closestLocation(targetLocation, locationData) {
    function vectorDistance(dx, dy) {
        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }

    function locationDistance(location1, location2) {
        var dx = location1.lat - location2.lat,
            dy = location1.lng - location2.lng;

        return vectorDistance(dx, dy);
    }

    return locationData.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
        var prevDistance = locationDistance(targetLocation , prev),
            currDistance = locationDistance(targetLocation , curr);


          return (prevDistance < currDistance) ? prev : curr;  

    });
}
```

The algorithm works well, but now I need to add a feature: `epsilon`

```
function closestLocation(targetLocation, locationData, epsilon) {
    function vectorDistance(dx, dy) {
        return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    }

    function locationDistance(location1, location2) {
        var dx = location1.lat - location2.lat,
            dy = location1.lng - location2.lng;

        return vectorDistance(dx, dy);
    }

    return locationData.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
        var prevDistance = locationDistance(targetLocation , prev),
            currDistance = locationDistance(targetLocation , curr);


          return (prevDistance < currDistance && Math.abs(prevDistance - currDistance) < epsilon) ? prev : curr;  

    });
}
```

I thought it would work, but it did not.

I want to return the object only when it is in a radious `epsilon`.

EDIT:

Input:

```
locationData = [{"lat":number, "lng":number, "title": "title"}, {"lat":number, "lng":number, "title": "title"}]

targetLocation = {"lat": number, "lng": number}
```

Output:

```
closest = {"lat":number, "lng":number, "title": "title"}
```

Comment: What are your inputs and what is the output (if not available what is the expected output)?

Comment: Usually the great circle calculation is used to compute distance when dealing with lat/long.

Comment: @Ding I updated my question

Comment: Either pre-filter the data set or check the distance once at the end.

Comment: Yes I am checking it in the end, but I think it would be more efficient if I can filter it in the reduce algorithm

Comment: I think you shouldn't miss the chance of using `Math.hypot(location1.lat - location2.lat, location1.lng - location2.lng)` instead of defining a `vectorDistance` and `locationDistance` functions here :)